# Analytical methods for solving polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Question is very simple: What *analytic*  methods (not numerical or approximation methods) do you know to solve this kind of polynomial?: $$x^4-2x^3+x^2-2x+1=0$$

Comment: I don't understand the question. All these methods involve basically factoring the polynomial. What are you asking?

Comment: It has two real roots and two complex.

Comment: Yes it's true but can you show me the way to prove it?

Comment: I know what you mean by *analytical*, but to me the processes involving limits of sequences and such work inside analysis, but the methods for finding the roots in terms of radicals and such would be *algebraic* because they rely on tools from abstract algebra :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is, of course, the general solution to the quartic, as noted in a comment.

Another way is to notice that the coefficients are symmetric. We therefore divide the equation by $x^2$ and rearrange the terms to get

$$\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right) -2\left(x+\frac 1x\right) + 1=0$$

We let $u=x+\frac 1x$ and note that

$$u^2-2=x^2+\frac 1{x^2}$$

So our equation becomes

$$u^2-2u-1=0$$

We can use this to get two solutions for $u$. We then use our definition of $u$ to get two $x$'s for each $u$, giving us four solutions to the original equation. And all this was done with simple algebra and solving three quadratic equations.

Note that, for real valued $x$, the expression $x+\frac 1x$ has a minimum absolute value of $2$. Thus, for any $u$ where $|u|<2$ the values of $x$ will be non-real. There are two real values of $x$ if $|u|>2$ and only one double-root if $|u|=2$. This answers the question in the comment on showing how many of the solutions are real numbers.

Since you just asked for analytical methods I assume you do not need me to carry this to completion and show the values of $x$.

Comment: It's exactly what I meant. I was just curious if exists any other kind of solution for this kind of polynomials. Can You say for sure that there are only two methods to solve that polynomial?

Comment: I am not an expert in Algebra so I cannot say for sure that there are no more exact methods to solve that polynomial. I can say that *I* do not know any others. There are, of course, many numerical, approximation methods.